# Spring-Boot: How to create Rest API service without using beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring-boot is the industry standard for creating REST API service in Java. You can see here a code example from the official documentation of sprint-boot:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Whereas spring-boot is a great solution for creating REST API, it seems from the documentation that I must use the Spring framework for dependency injection.
I want to use spring-boot, but I don't want to use any dependency injection framework. My intention is just to run a "public static void main" method and do all the injection inside this method.

Do you know how to do it? Or should I pick another framework?

Comment: Why use Spring then?  Just write it all yourself.  What's the reason for your concern?  Too many JARs?   Start up time for a lambda?  It'd be informative to know the reasons behind your thinking.

Comment: @duffymo I just don't like dependency-injection frameworks. Feels like too much magic.

Comment: Spring is built for that reason, if you do not want to use dependency injection or beans, spring is not a tool for you. As a lad said, write it yourself then.

Comment: @CrazySynthax you can create both command line apps as well as webapps with spring boot.
You can use commandlinerunner(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html) to run your script at startup regardless any type of application. I would highly recommend you to understand more about DI before thinking about not using it.
Its great solution of managing java bean dependencies.
also still you can benifit from spring boot features like convention over configuration, spring boot starters and autoconfiguration....

Comment: If you use spring boot then spring boot itself will be using spring dependency injection, and if you want to change its configuration, you will likely have to use dependency injection. But once you've set up your code's entry point, there's no reason why you can't create your services and domain objects without it. That said, dependency injection has a lot of advantages.

Comment: That sounds like „I want to use Unix command line tools but I do not want to use Unix“

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is within the roots of your question.

You are saying "I want to use Spring Boot, but I don't want to use Spring Framework." Seems like you don't completely understand what is `Spring Boot` and what is `Spring Framework`.

From official [Spring page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot):

> Spring Boot makes it easy to create stand-alone, production-grade
> Spring based Applications that you can "just run".
>
> We take an opinionated view of the Spring platform and third-party
> libraries so you can get started with minimum fuss. Most Spring Boot
> applications need minimal Spring configuration.

What it means is that Spring Boot is just a set of **settings**, or you can say **preconfigurations** FOR Spring Framework generally.

***But what is Spring Framework?***

The core concept of `Spring Framework` is so called `IoC Container` (Inversion of Control). Or simply saying, **IT IS ALL ABOUT DEPENDENCY INJECTION**. There is a thing called Application context, which is managed by Spring Framework.

---

Now another question. **Why would you not** use Spring Framework? What's exactly something you don't like with it? Dependency Injection? You want to always create a new object? Why?

Again, in the core, by default, Spring Framework creates Beans using `Singleton` pattern, which basically beans that, one instance of a class is getting created, and then it is stored inside Application Context by Spring Framework. When you will use it, Spring Framework IoC Container `will just fetch it` for you, not create it again. And this is absolutely great, since you are saving a lot of memory.

Spring Framework also lets you change that behaviour, so you can select Bean to be not Singleton, but `Prototype`, which basically means, each time you call an object is getting created. Each call, each new object.

And this is cool that Spring Framework actually gives you this choice, even though you don't really need it 99/100 time.

---

If you are sure that `Spring` is something you don't want to use, if you want to go deeper, then there is an entire `Java EE` (today also called **Jakarta EE**) which you can use, which will give a lot more freedom.

Frameworks won't give you much freedom, that's the purpose of frameworks. "Set of rules, premanaged for you, to make your life easier."